# How to set that a column can't be empty string? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I want to **forbid that in database is saved empty user** ,with an empty string name,email,phone. And I want to test it.

**My migration** :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user1s', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("name");
        $table->string("email");
        $table->string("phone_number");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**PageController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
        $this->validate($request , [
            'name' =>'required' ,
            'email' =>'required' ,
            'phone_number' =>'required' ,   
            ]);

        $user= new User1;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email =  $request->email;
        $user->phone_number =  $request->phone_number;

        $user->save();

    return redirect('/thankyou');

}
```

**When I want to test with this test it saves an empty user in database and returns error ...... true is false**

```
public function testnonEmptyInput(){

    $user1=New User1;
    $user1->name="";
    $user1->email="";
    $user1->phone_number="";

    $this->assertFalse($user1->save());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set a minimum length constraint for a string (atleast in MySQL).

Here you can implement a minimum length constraint through the constraints during your validation using something like this.

```
 $this->validate($request , [
            'name' =>'required|min:1' ,
            'email' =>'required' ,
            'phone_number' =>'required' ,   
            ]);
```

If you insist on not being able to even save a model with an empty string, you can implement that through Model Events - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events

To add the constraint, you can add the following code to User1.php,

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($u) {
      if(empty($u->name)) {
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

(I've only implemented the constraints for a non-empty name. You can extrapolate the same for implementing constraints for the email address and phone number.)